# Unable to authenticate LinkedIn Python API client using Oauth2.0

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to authenticate the LinkedIn API to retrieve data from company pages using my LinkedIn App credentials.

Under Oauth 2.0 settings:

Redirect URLs:
http://localhost:8000/

Wasn't entirely sure which URLS to add in above.

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests_oauthlib.compliance_fixes import linkedin_compliance_fix


# Credentials you get from registering a new application
client_id = '*********'
client_secret = '********'
redirect_url = 'http://localhost:8000/'

# OAuth endpoints given in the LinkedIn API documentation (you can check for the latest updates)
authorization_base_url ='https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'

# Authorized Redirect URL (from LinkedIn configuration)
linkedin = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_url)
linkedin = linkedin_compliance_fix(linkedin)

# Redirect user to LinkedIn for authorization
authorization_url, state = 
linkedin.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
print('Please go here and authorize,', authorization_url)

# Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
redirect_response = input('Paste the full redirect URL here:')

# Fetch the access token
linkedin.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret,
                 authorization_response=redirect_response)

# Fetch a protected resource, i.e. user profile
r = linkedin.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~')
print(r.content)
```

After opening the URL and logging in & authorizing the client, I keep getting this error:
InvalidClientIdError: (invalid_request) A required parameter "client_id" is missing

I'm sure these are the most up to date URLs to use for LinkedIn

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but I came across this same problem today.

The solution lies in passing a flag that forces the use of client_id:

```
linkedin.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret, authorization_response=redirect_response, include_client_id=True)
```

I hope that helps!